# Does Sqlite have the concept of a schema in naming tables/views?

Tags: sqlite

From everything I've read and searched on I think the answer is no because it's never mentioned. But I never saw an explicit no.

Does Sqlite allow for a schema like in Sql Server you can have **dbo.** Employee.FirstName? Or is it limited to Employee.FirstName?

thanks - dave

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't think sqlite has the exact same concept as schemas have in some other databases but you can attach several databases and operate on them by name.
e.g.

```
$ sqlite3 mydb1
SQLite version 3.20.1 2017-08-24 16:21:36
sqlite> create table test1 (id int);  insert into test1 values (1);
sqlite> .tables
test1
```

Above we just have 1 database, which is the default database and doesn't need to be prefixed by the name of the database. However the name of this default default database is `main` , so we can do:

```
sqlite> select * from test1;
1
sqlite> select * from main.test1;
1
```

We can attach another database, which will be available under the name `myotherdb`.

```
sqlite> attach database 'myotherdb' as 'myotherdb';
sqlite> create table myotherdb.test1 (id int);  insert into myotherdb.test1 values (2);
```

Now we can use `myotherdb` to refer to this new database, and no prefix or the `main` prefix to refer to the first/default database

```
sqlite> select * from myotherdb.test1 where myotherdb.test1.id > 0;
2
sqlite> select * from test1 where test1.id > 0;
1
sqlite> select * from main.test1 where main.test1.id > 0;
1
```

Note that this will create 2 different database files

```
sqlite> .databases
main: /tmp/mydb1
myotherdb: /tmp/myotherdb
```

These 2 databases files can be opened individually later on.

Comment: Are these then 2 distinct files? Or are they both in a single file? If the same file then this is similar to the use of it in Sql Server, etc.

Comment: It creates 2 files.

Comment: Ok, so I think (I'm sort-of guessing here) that sqlite lets you name each DB when it opens the DB, but that name exists only in the application until it closes a DB and does not exist in the DB itself. And the next time around different names could be used. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, certainly. You could open just the `/tmp/myotherdb` file in the next session, and that would be the `main` database. The name is specified in the `ATTACH` statement, `ATTACH` is per session, it's not persisted anywhere.

Comment: Thank you. And I take this (others might differ) that the answer is no.